# Trying to share previously deleted project in SVN I get odd message

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

I erroneously shared a locally developed project into trunk. I deleted it in Eclipse SVN Repository Exploring view. It no longer appears in the repository view. Then I tried to share the project into the correct branch and I get this message:

> The project "Project1" already exists in repository and has some
>   content. To connect the local project to the specified location, the
>   repository folder content should be checked out. Please consider that
>   applying local changes can cause resource conflicts. For example, if
>   the local file has the same name as the remote directory the working
>   copy of the file will be obstructed.
>
> Do you wish to proceed ?

There is no project with that name in SVN that I can see.

After trying unsuccessfully to find any references to this message I chose yes for proceed. Then it looked like it was uploading multiple projects and files that didn't belong to this project -- the title on the dialog box was Share Projects rather than Share Project as well -- so I pressed cancel.

Anybody know what is happening here?

Comment: I'm no expert when it comes to the Eclipse IDE, so I may be way off-base here, but it sounds like Eclipse manages its own mappings to SVN checkouts and repositories. Remove the mapping that it's complaining about and then retry?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It's not clear to me that the issue is on the client side. And I don't think that mapping is easily manipulable. But I plan to try to submit the project commit from another account.